# How to map a Array and create a Object from it?

Tags: javascript

Below is my code....

```
var temp = {};
[{group_id : "1111"}, {group_id: "2222"}].map(function(ele, index) {
    var group_id = ele.group_id;
    temp.group_id = {value: 0}
});
```

After run this code, the temp object is

```
 {group_id : {value : 0}
```

But what I want is

```
{ {"1111" : {value : 0}}, {"2222" : {value : 0}} }
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You can't. That is not a valid object. Do you want to get an array instead?

Comment: Anyway, I can get that result?

Comment: `[ {"1111" : {value : 0}}, {"2222" : {value : 0}} ]` Might be you are expecting

Comment: I think "temp" should be an array

Comment: @lsv - read the question

Comment: is what you want  `{ "1111" : {value : 0}, "2222" : {value : 0} }`

Comment: `Anyway, I can get that result?` - you've just been told the result you are asking for is invalid ... and you still want it? Wow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using `temp.group_id` use `temp[group_id]`.

Comment: no need to use `.map` either as the returned array is immediately discarded

Answer (score 0):

> But what I want is
>
> ```
> { {"1111" : {value : 0}}, {"2222" : {value : 0}} }
> ```

You can utilize an array to store objects where results would be

```
[
  {
    "1111": {
      "value": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "2222": {
      "value": 0
    }
  }
]
```

```
var obj = [{group_id : "1111"}, {group_id: "2222"}];
var res = obj.map(o => ({[o.group_id]:{value:0}}));
```

Answer (score 0):

As your current noted expected result is not a valid JSON structure.

Instead I am writing my solution based on the assumption that your expected result is: 
`{ "1111" : {value : 0}, "2222" : {value : 0} }` and since the end result is an object, using `map` would not be appropriate as it returns an Array. So my solution is based on the `reduce` API.

```js
function initObject(obj, currElement) {
  obj[currElement.group_id] = { value: 0 };
  return obj;
}

console.log([{group_id : "1111"}, {group_id: "2222"}].reduce(initObject, {}));
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use the reduce Fn to reduce your array to object. As the
>   expectation of your output is not a valid JSON, the result of a valid
>   JSON structure that can be obtained is below. Pls modify your question
>   for a valid result set if this is not the case.

```js
var temp = [{group_id : "1111"}, {group_id: "2222"}].reduce(function(obj, key) {
 
     obj[key.group_id] = {value: 0};
     return obj;
    
} , {});
console.log(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your map function is fine, though the structure of object that you wanna achieve is little bit wrong.

In a object, the values exist as key-value pair, so there has to be a key against the `temp` object. Or you can enclose everything as an array.

SO

```js
var temp = {};
[{group_id : "1111"}, {group_id: "2222"}]
.map(function(ele) {
    var group_id = ele.group_id;
    temp[group_id] = {value: 0}
});
```

will give you `temp` as

```
{"1111":{value: 0}, "2222":{value: 0}}
```

And for array, your code can go like following:

```js
var temp = [];
[{group_id : "1111"}, {group_id: "2222"}]
.map(function(ele) {
  var obj = {};
  obj[ele.group_id] = {value: 0}
  temp.push(obj)
});
```

This will give you `temp` as

```
[{"1111":{value: 0}}, {"2222": {value: 0}}]
```

You can use any one of them, both are good, though depends on how you wanna use `temp` later in you code.